# There exist vectors $p$ and $d$ such that the line containing $a$ and $b$ can be expressed in the form $v = p+d t.$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let
$$a = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \\ -4 \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad b = \begin{pmatrix} -11 \\ 1 \\ 28 \end{pmatrix}.$$

There exist vectors $p$ and $d$ such that the line containing $a$ and $b$ can be expressed in the form
$$v = p+d t.$$
Furthermore, for a certain choice of $d$, it is the case that for all points $v$ lying on the same side of $a$ that $b$ lies on, the distance between $v$ and $a$ is $t$. Find $d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\vec d=\frac{\vec b-\vec a}{||\vec b-\vec a||}=\frac1{36}\begin{bmatrix}-16\\4\\32\end{bmatrix}=\frac19\begin{bmatrix}-4\\\ \ 1\\ \ \ 8\end{bmatrix}$$ be a unit vector pointing from $\vec a$ to $\vec b$. And let $\vec p=\vec a$.

Now,

$$\vec v=\vec p+t\vec d=\begin{bmatrix}\ \ 5\\-3\\-4\end{bmatrix}+\frac t9\begin{bmatrix}-4\\\ \ 1\\ \ \ 8\end{bmatrix}$$
is a line that contains $\vec a$ and $\vec b$. (For $t=0$, we have  $\vec v=\vec a$ and for $t=||\vec b-\vec a||=36$, we have $\vec v=\vec b$.)

Furthermore, if $t$ is increasing through positive numbers then we go further away from $\vec a$ (and at $t=36$ we reach $\vec b$.) That is, lying on the $\vec b$ side of $\vec a$ is equivalent to belonging to positive $t$s.

So, take a positive $t$ and calculate the distance of $$\begin{bmatrix}\ \ 5\\-3\\-4\end{bmatrix}+\frac t9\begin{bmatrix}-4\\\ \ 1\\ \ \ 8\end{bmatrix}$$ from $\vec a$. That is, let's consider the length of the following vector$$\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}-\left(\begin{bmatrix}\ \ 5\\-3\\-4\end{bmatrix}+\frac t9\begin{bmatrix}-4\\\ \ 1\\ \ \ 8\end{bmatrix}\right)=$$
$$=\frac t9\begin{bmatrix}-4\\\ \ 1\\ \ \ 8\end{bmatrix}.$$

This length is exactly $t$. And this is what we needed.